# cmake find_library with version number

Tags: c++, c, windows, cmake

I have a library in different flavours `libsoci-3.2.2_core_s.a` `libsoci-3.2.2_core_sd.a` etc.. One is a static debug version or a static release version and some other versions as well (unicode, DLL, etc.).

Now when I use this cmake statement it finds the first library instead of the correct one.

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${SOCI_LIBRARY_PATH})
find_library(SOCI_LIBRARY
    NAMES "soci-3.2.2_core_${UNICODE_FLAG}s${BUILD_TYPE_FLAG}"
    HINTS "${SOCI_LIBRARY_PATH}"
)
message("SOCI_SEARCHNAME: soci-3.2.2_core_s${BUILD_TYPE_FLAG}")
message("SOCI_FOUND: ${SOCI_LIBRARY}   soci-3.2.2_core_s${BUILD_TYPE_FLAG}")
```

Currently I have only static versions of this lib, so I put the 's' hardcoded. The `BUILD_TYPE_FLAG` is 'd'  for the debug or empty and in this case it is definitely 'd' but cmake always returns

```
d:\src\c\github\build\Datinator>make
SOCI_SEARCHNAME: soci-3.2.2_core_sd
SOCI_FOUND: d:/opt/soci/lib/libsoci-3.2.2_core_s.a   soci-3.2.2_core_sd
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

So what do I have to do, that cmake finds the correct library version, apart from putting it in separate directories (which I don't like).

Also, is there some way that cmake finds the versionnumber `3.2.2` itself or do I have to hardcode this?

Comment: How did you compile your FindSOCI_LIBRARY.cmake or SociXXXX.cmake file or who provided it. It is probably not made correctly as recommended by KitWare

Comment: @Devolus: Try rerun cmake after removing `SOCI_LIBRARY` variable from the cache: `cmake -U SOCI_LIBRARY <source-dir>`. The thing is that result of `find_library` is cached, and the command does nothing if its first argument's variable is already set.

Comment: @Jens, I made it myself, and I have already used it,but with static projectfiles. Now I'm converting my project to cmake and it is much more pain then I though it would be...

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks! That solved it. :)

Comment: @Devolus I went through the same pain about a year ago. I found this page and its successor quite useful. http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file Once you have solved the worst problems, you never go back.

Comment: @Jens, thanks for the link. Setting up a multiplatform buildsystem is always a pain, so seeing cmake I realized that it takes a lot of that away and decided to convert my project. :) And there is always a learning curve when doing something new anyway.